# How to inject Javascript at Document Start using C# on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to port an app from Swift (iOS only) to C# in Visual Studio - and it's going (slightly) well.  I'm having some Android troubles though (many of them - but only one for this question!)

The page loads correctly in the webview of the Android version of the app - but the Javascript doesn't execute until after the page has rendered, the result being that the App Store advert is displayed briefly before it disappears.

My iOS app works correctly - the source code for the iOS version is here:

```
public class PortalViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<PortalView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler, IWKNavigationDelegate {

    private class NavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate {
        private readonly WeakReference<PortalViewRenderer> _webView;

        public NavigationDelegate(PortalViewRenderer webView) {
            _webView = new WeakReference<PortalViewRenderer>(webView);
        }

        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation) {
        }

        public override void DidStartProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation) {
            NSUrl currentURL = webView.Url;
            var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

            if (current != NetworkAccess.Internet) {
                if (!(currentURL.AbsoluteString.Contains("file://"))) {
                    string noConnectionPath = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "Common/NoInternet.html");
                    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(NSUrl.FromString(noConnectionPath)));
                }
            }
        }

        public override void DidFailNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error) {

        }

        public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler) {
            NSUrl url = navigationAction.Request.Url;
            if (url != null) {
                if (url.Host == "<website url>" || url.AbsoluteString.Contains("file://")) {
                    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
                } else if (url.AbsoluteString.Contains("<website url>/mydavylamp/timeout")) {
                    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel);
                    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(NSUrl.FromString(Element.Uri)));
                } else {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    WKUserContentController userController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<PortalView> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        var javaScriptFunction = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Common/HideAppStoreAds.js");

        if (Control == null) {
            userController = new WKUserContentController();
            var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(javaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, false);
            userController.AddUserScript(script);
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "invokeAction");

            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            webView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(0x11, 0x25, 0x43);
            webView.ScrollView.BackgroundColor = webView.BackgroundColor;
            webView.CustomUserAgent = "headbanger.davylamp.ios";
            webView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
            webView.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
            webView.AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false;
            webView.ContentMode = UIKit.UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
            webView.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate(this);

            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
            var portalView = e.OldElement as PortalView;
            portalView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(NSUrl.FromString(Element.Uri)));
        }
    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message) {
        Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
    }
}
```

The Android version is as follows (it doesn't do so much yet, because I haven't worked out how to set policies etc. yet) but my main concern is that I can't get the Javascript to run at the correct time (as set on the iOS version using WKUserScriptInjectionTime which doesn't seem to have an Android equivalent)

```
public class JavascriptWebViewClient : WebViewClient {
    string _javascript;

    public JavascriptWebViewClient(string javascript) {
        _javascript = javascript;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url) {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
    }
}

public class PortalViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<PortalView, Android.Webkit.WebView> {
    Context _context;

    public PortalViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<PortalView> e) {
        string javascriptFunction;

        Android.Content.Res.AssetManager assets = _context.Assets;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Common/HideAppStoreAds.js"))) {
            javascriptFunction = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null) {
            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {javascriptFunction}"));
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            var portalView = e.OldElement as PortalView;
            portalView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            Control.LoadUrl($"{Element.Uri}");
        }
    }
}
```

The (common) Javascript is as follows:

```
var styleTag = document.createElement("style");
styleTag.textContent = '.mobile-apps {display:none;}';
document.documentElement.appendChild(styleTag);
```

I've googled for the magic spell, but I can't seem to find any guides on how to build a webview for Android in C# - and particularly not for iOS developers!

As always, any help that anyone can provide will be gratefully received.

Comment: Generally, js is injected in OnPageFinished,you could try to inject js `view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);` in `OnPageStarted`

Comment: OnPageFInished doesn't work in all scenarios - and I tried that but it didn't work.  I'm now pondering if I need to keep two webviews and swap them over once the javascript completes.  But that seems wasteful and I'm not very happy about a wasteful solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, for my use case, seems to be as follows.

The Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) for *onPageCommitVisible* says that:

> This callback can be used to determine the point at which it is safe to make a recycled WebView visible, ensuring that no stale content is shown. It is called at the earliest point at which it can be guaranteed that WebView#onDraw will no longer draw any content from previous navigations. The next draw will display either the WebView#setBackgroundColor of the WebView, or some of the contents of the newly loaded page.

To my mind, this means that the HTML has loaded (although not necessarily any other resources) and the page might start to be rendered (although, crucially, it won't be rendered until this callback completes.)

I used the following code:

```
    public override void OnPageCommitVisible(WebView view, string url) {
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
        base.OnPageCommitVisible(view, url);
    }
```

and it seems to work correctly.  I hope that this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to override **OnPageCommitVisible** method:

```
public override void OnPageCommitVisible(AWebView view, string url)
    {
       //Insert javascript injection first
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
        base.OnPageCommitVisible(view, url);
    }
```

It fires Certainly.
Have a good code!

Comment: That's what my previous answer says, from July 31st 2019.